# International Orange?

Tags: spacesuits, color

Was the Launch Entry Suit, the pumpkin suit, the first time any space agency used the color [International Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_orange) in anything intended to go into space?

From [International orange; Astronautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_orange#Astronautics):

> The Advanced Crew Escape Suits pressure suits worn by NASA astronauts and the previous Launch Entry Suit use this color,<sup>4,5</sup> as opposed to the lighter tone of safety orange used by the United States Air Force's high-altitude suits. This was also planned for the new Constellation Space Suit systems that were to be flight-ready by 2015.
>
> <sup>4</sup>[Why Are Astronauts' Spacesuits Orange?](http://www.lifeslittlemysteries.com/why-are-astronauts-spacesuits-orange-0825/)
>
> <sup>5</sup>[NASA - The Spacesuit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100520023431/http://www.nasa.gov/externalflash/nasa_spacesuit/). Archived from the [original](http://www.nasa.gov/externalflash/nasa_spacesuit/) on 2010-05-20.

[image] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Launch_entry_suit.jpg) click for full size.

Comment: Is "international orange" the intent of those suits? Or is it visibility in possible low visibility scenarios? I think most color choices are functional.

Comment: I've added some links, feel fee to roll back if you think it's too cluttered.

Comment: Related, not duplicates: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31982/26446 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/87/26446

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not explain what's supposed to be "international" about the color. In fact it seems to me to be entirely made up -- none of the references it provides support that name in particular.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Notably, the so called "black boxes" on aircraft, despite the name, are also that color for the same reason.

Comment: @darrelhoffman the black boxes' name alludes to black box programming- right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yuri Gagarin wore the first space suit in 1961, the [SK-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK-1_spacesuit).  It was orange.

[image: SK-1 spacesuit]

Answer (score 7):

No, it was not. The Apollo parachutes had orange gores.

[image]
Image source: https://www.history.com/news/moon-landing-technology-inventions-computers-heat-shield-rovers

Comment: I've just asked [Does the FAA still license the people who fold human-rated reentry parachutes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38796/12102)